# Java is giving me different results for the same process

Tags: java, arrays, methods

what i mainly want to know is : 
in the line `public static void val(int[] x)` what does the `(int[] x)` do?
Also: why am i getting the final added up values when i ask

```
for(int y:i){
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

but not for:

```
int y=2+i2;
    System.out.println(y);
```

why isnt the vale() method not converting the "i2" value to "x" immediately and then continuing the compilation by using the "x" value for subsequent 'i2" calculations....sorry if my question is vague....i just dont know how else to put it....thanks

complete code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] i = { 25, 22 };
    int i2 = 41;
    val(i);
    for (int y : i) {
        System.out.println(y);
    }
    vale(i2);
    int y = 2 + i2;
    System.out.println(y);

}

public static void val(int[] x) {
    for (int c = 0; c < x.length; c++) {
        x[c] *= 2;
    }

}

public static void vale(int x) {
    x += 23;
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: Your method `vale(int x)` makes no sense. You can't reaffect a variable like that. You have to return the result and the caller has to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Java always passes arguments by value, never by reference (not only primitive types, reference types as well). This is why your `vale(int x)` method doesn't work.

Have a look at this article, it explains everything: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read about pass by value and reference in Java. Regarding your questions, both `val(i)` & `vale(i2)` are technically pass by value. Since array is an object type, its reference is passed to the method in case of `val(i)` and hence you could see the modifications when you print the reference. However, `vale(i2)` takes a primitive integer type as parameter and thus the modifications within the method doesn't affect the original value. To understand this better you  can modify your val(int[] x) method as follows:

```
    public static void val(int[] x) {
        x = new int[] {35, 57};
        for (int c = 0; c < x.length; c++) {
            x[c] *= 2;
        }
    }
```

I just added `x = new int[] {35, 57};` which would make the value of `x` point to a different reference and not affect the original value. Hope this clarifies!

Answer (score -1):

- Your method val(int[] x) accomplishes absolutely nothing in this code.  It returns void(nothing) to the main() function and the operations you preform inside val() with your array x are done on a copy of x...

possible fix:

```
public static int[] val(int[] x){
int[] newarr = new int[x.length]; 
for (int c=0; c<x.length;c++){
    newarr[c] = x[c]*2;
}
return newarr;
}
```

in main:

```
int[] i={25,22};

i = val(i); // creates an array with every element doubled and assigns it to i
```

- same story with vale() !